# При удалении не последнего по счету элемента localStorage остается undefined

Tags: javascript, localstorage, reactjs

Сохраняю данные в localStorage, каждая запись хранит определенную строку, каждая запись имеет название с нумерацией, к примеру task1, task2 и так далее. На странице имееются кнопки, для удаления данных записей по одной. Проблема вот в чем, если я удаляю записи с последней, то все нормально, а если не последнюю, то после обновления страницы, она вновь появится, но строка уже будет undefined. Например: есть task1, task2 и task3, я удаляю task3, после обновления страницы она не появляется вновь, однако, если удалю task1 или/и task2, они восстановятся со строками undefined.

Функция Создания элемента на странице и запись его текста в localStorage:

```js
export function CreateTask(text)
{
    if (document.getElementById('add-task-input') != null) {
        let taskDiv = document.createElement('div');
        let taskTextTag = document.createElement('p');
        let buttonTaskRemove = document.createElement('img');

        taskDiv.setAttribute('id', 'todo-task');
        buttonTaskRemove.setAttribute('id', 'button-task-remove');
        buttonTaskRemove.setAttribute('src', './remove-task-icon.png');
        taskTextTag.setAttribute('onclick', 'eval("' +
            'if (this.style.textDecoration == `line-through`) this.style.textDecoration = `none`;' +
            'else this.style.textDecoration = `line-through`")');
        taskTextTag.setAttribute('id', 'label-task');
        buttonTaskRemove.addEventListener('click', RemoveTaskButtonClick);

        if (text == '')
        {
            taskTextTag.innerHTML = document.getElementById('add-task-input').value;
            document.getElementById('add-task-input').value = '';
        }
        else
        {
            taskTextTag.innerHTML = text;
        }

        taskDiv.appendChild(taskTextTag);
        taskDiv.appendChild(buttonTaskRemove);
        document.getElementById('root').appendChild(taskDiv);

        countTask++;

        localStorage.setItem(`task${countTask}`, text);
    }
}
```

Функция загрузки записей из localStorage на страницу:

```js
export function LoadTasks()
{
    if (localStorage.length != 0)
    {
        for (let i = 1; i < localStorage.length + 1; i++)
        {
            CreateTask(localStorage[`task${i}`]);
        }
    }
}
```

Функция удаления записи из localStorage:

```js
function RemoveTaskButtonClick()
{
    for (let i = 1; i < localStorage.length + 1; i++)
    {
        if (localStorage[`task${i}`] == this.parentElement.innerText)
        {
            //delete localStorage[`task${i}`];
            window.localStorage.removeItem(`task${i}`);
        }
    }
    this.parentElement.remove();
}
```

Проект пишу на React.JS

Comment: А не надо использовать ключи с названиями, зависящими от индекса.

Comment: @igor, и как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых. Итерировать по ключам `localStorage`, хранящим элементы массивов, - изначально порочный подход. Все развалится, когда Вам понадобится сохранить в `localStorage` что-нибудь еще.

Во-вторых. Храните весь массив элементов под одним ключом - как сериализованные данные. Удаляйте/добавляйте/изменяйте элементы в массиве - сохраняйте массив в `localStorage` на каждую такую операцию.

```
let arrTasks = [];
if (localStorage['myTasks'])
  arrTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage['myTasks']);

...

localStorage['myTasks'] = JSON.stringify(arrTasks);
```

Comment: Нуу, изначально там не массив, а просто множество объектов с одним id. Ну а за то что направили, благодарю

Comment: @Yatov "Нуу, изначально там не массив" - дурацкое возражение, не имеющее отношения к тому, что я написал.

Comment: почему же, вы написали, что хранятся элементы массива, а у меня нигде массива нету и localStorage помнится мне тоже не является массивом

Comment: @Yatov Замените слово "массив" на "коллекция" или "набор однородных данных".

Comment: аа, хм, понял, спасибо за пояснение

Comment: воспользовался вашим способом, в массив все записывается, массив корректно сериализуется в json объект, однако при записи в localStorage вашим способом записывается пустой массив, то есть просто []

Comment: @Yatov Мне через интернет плохо виден Ваш код.

Comment: пардон, забыл прикрепить код. Вот весь код js файла, просто, если увидеть весь код так понятнее будет, где что... https://pastebin.com/Ajas9HLp

Comment: @Yatov Вы не читаете сохраненные данные.

Comment: я понял, я просто пытался сначала записать и посмотреть в хранилище браузера, там отображается как []. Ну ладно, попробую прочитать

Comment: вот - https://pastebin.com/9RLqWcPE ... Сделал так же с загрузкой, просто читает опять же, как будто ничего нету. Добавил на сайте туда два элемента, при чтении пробую в alert выводить, дважды появляется, то есть по идее создаются две пустые ячейки

Comment: @Yatov Я ничего не понял. Что где "дважды появляется"?

Comment: @Yatov Это что значит - `if (!document.getElementById('add-task-input').value == '')`?

Comment: я же говорю, alert. В коде видно, я в массив десериализовал json объект, в alert вывожу taskList(сам массив), появляется сначала один пустой alert, закрываю его и сразу же второй, закрываю его и все. Это после создания двух элементов и обновления страницы(при обновлении/закрытии страницы все нужные данные туда записываются, сериализуются и записываются в localStorage)

Comment: я думал понятно... Я проверяю, если поле ввода не пустое, то создаем объект, который содержит текст введенный пользователем, если пустой, то выводит сообщение, что невозможно создать пустой объект

Comment: @Yatov Нет, непонятно. Вы хотели сказать `if (document.getElementById('add-task-input').value != '')`?

Comment: суть одна. мой вариант: если не элемент с id add-task-input пустой, то...
Ваш вариант: если элемент с id add-task-input не пустой, то...
Помимо js я еще много писал на C# и такие конструкции много где применяются. Все же, давайте вернемся к делу. Как можно исправить то, что в localStorage записывается []?

Comment: @Yatov Мне начинает надоедать с Вами общаться. Создайте работающий пример в jsFiddle, и я, может быть, его починю.

Comment: пардон, что так поздно, но спасибо, уже не надо, в jsFiddle написал подобный код, все работает, покопался в своем и разобрался в чем дело

Comment: @Yatov Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: аа, да, ок. Спасибо, и вам того же )